# What is the Uniswap version 3 factory address?

Tags: uniswap

The router address to the uniswap version 3 exchange is 0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45. What is the factory address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all address here - https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments